# Ionic app not showing debug log

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have created a ionic based app that using phonegap, After installing in my device it not showing any logs when i using debug tool in phonegap. I'm not able to make http call using $http.post method. I don't know anything i missed.

Comment: The log needs the console-plugin http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=console and for the requests you need the whitelist-plugin http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=whitelist

Comment: It's working after adding this plugin. Please post your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The log needs the console-plugin cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=console and for the requests you need the whitelist-plugin cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=whitelist

Most of these plugins works only for Android 4.0.0 or above